# Reorder action keys?

Tags: pc, xcom-enemy-unknown

So the order of the actions are different for the different classes. Luckily "fire" is always on 1, but I'd like "overwatch" to always be on key 2.

Now it changes between 3 and 4 depending on the current type of soldier. Actions that are the same for all classes should always be mapped to the same keys I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the order of the numbered actions, but you can press `Y` for overwatch.  There is also `B` for *Hunker Down*, `R` for *Reload* and `X` for switching weapons.

These keys also have the advantage that they perform the action immediately without an additional confirmation.

You can change these hotkeys under Esc->Options->Interface->Tactical Shortcuts.

Comment: In XCOM: Enemy Within, the "Hunker Down" shortcut has been inexplicably removed.